# I installed Ubuntu on my MacBook 2,1 it worked fine for many days, but now it has a white flash screen with question marked folder when booting

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, data-recovery, macosx, white-screen

Here is a picture of the screen.
[image: Flashing white screen with a question marked folder]

Comment: That screen means the computer cannot find a bootable device. You may have a bad SSD if this happened without provocation.

Comment: Do I need to replace SSD?

Comment: Boot a live linux und look if your harddrive is shown there.